# attempt to index number with 'SetAsync' when writing to the DataStore

Tags: lua, roblox

When I try and save a table (encoded into a json format) through SetAsync, it provides me with this error:

"ServerScriptService.InventoryService.main:59: attempt to index number with 'SetAsync'  -  Server"

I have encoded the table with HTTP:JSONEncode() and I decode it when its read again.
heres an example of the table:

```
{
 ["A"] = {
    ["x"] = 98,
    ["y"] = "xyz",
    ["z"] = 15
         },
 ["B"] = {
    ["c"] = "XYZ",
    ["d"] = 0, 0, 0,
    ["e"] = "22",
    ["f"] = "xyz"
         }
}
```

Here is the Sample code

```
local Datastore = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
local RunService = game:GetService('RunService')
local HTTP = game:GetService('HttpService')
local item_data = Datastore:GetDataStore("Items")


local function save(Player:Player)
    local item_data = {} --contains data created by the user
    local savedata = {}
    
    --PLAYER_DATA--
    if savedata[Player] == "ERR" then return end
    local suc, err = pcall(function() 
        player_data:SetAsync(Player.UserId, savedata)
    end)

    if err then 
        warn("Unable to save data for"..Player.Name,err) 
    end
    --ITEM_DATA--
    if item_data[Player] == "ERR" then return end
    local suc, err = pcall(function()
    local item_json = HTTP:JSONEncode(item_data)
    itemdata:SetAsync(Player.UserId,item_json)
    end)

    if err then 
        warn("Unable to save data for "..Player.Name,err) 
    end

end

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(Player) 
    local suc, err = pcall(function() 
        data = player_data:GetAsync(Player.UserId) or "0"
        itemdata = HTTP:JSONDecode(item_data:GetAsync(Player.UserId) or "0")
        itemdata = HTTP:JSONDecode(itemdata)
    end)
    
    if suc then 
        savedata[Player] = data
    else 
        savedata[Player] = "ERR"
        warn("Error fetching "..Player.Name.."'s data.",err)
    end
end)
game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(Player)
    save(Player)
end)

game:BindToClose(function() -- (only needed inside Studio)
    print('BindToClose')
    if RunService:IsStudio() then -- (only needed inside Studio)
        wait(3) -- this will force the "SetAsync" above to complete 
    end
end)
```

Thanks in advance, any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```lua
itemdata = HTTP:JSONDecode(item_data:GetAsync(Player.UserId) or "0")
itemdata = HTTP:JSONDecode(itemdata)
```

Not sure why you decode it twice here but take a look at `or "0"`. That means `itemdata` might end up as `0`

```lua
itemdata:SetAsync(Player.UserId,item_json)
```

And here you try to call it. That's why it complains about calling a number.

I assume you meant to use `item_data`, which is a DataStore. Please use more descriptive names here to avoid such confusion :)